# Freezing screen since my last reboot

Tags: boot, graphics, freeze

It’s been 6 months that I use Ubuntu (22.04) on my Lenovo laptop (2022). It was working very well until now, and I can’t find the root of the problem so I’m asking a question here.

Last time, when I rebooted my laptop, I noticed that my screen now freezes every 2 seconds. If I move my mouse, it takes 2 seconds to change its position. If I switch tab, it also takes 2 seconds,... I observe this freezing at the very beginning of the booting, when I’m entering the password to unlock the disk encryption (it takes 2 seconds to have the characters updated on the screen but it’s really just a visual bug).

However, the system seems completely healthy. I checked the CPU&Memory usage, and its consuming almost nothing. I updated&upgraded the system to the last version, set the performance to the highest,...

I also checked and tested all the posts where a similar issue was being described, but nothing worked. I also noticed that when I start my laptop from recovery mode, there’s no freezing (but some graphical settings are disabled). So I think that this is related to a setting in my graphical device, but I have no clue how to fix it.

If there’s anyone who has an idea how to fix it, I would be glad to test it & provide additional information. Otherwise I would have no other choice than uninstall-reinstall the system.

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully found the solution everything works perfectly now. For those who might have the same problem as me here is the solution that I’ve found (source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000829)

In a terminal, enter `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then find the line “GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“. Remove the word “nomodeset” if existing and add `i915.enable_psr=0` inside the “”.

After that do `sudo update-grub` and reboot your system `sudo reboot now` and that should work.

For information, this solution has initially been provided for a Dell Latitude laptop (see the link above), but mine (Lenovo Yoga) also works.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I managed to remove the screen lags by setting ‘nomodeset’ in grub. However, this removes ergonomics features like switching desktop using trackpad motions, zoom mode in firefox,…

So if someone knows what would make such an error, I’d be very glad if you share me your knowledge.

For information: I’m running Ubuntu 22.04, my laptop has no GPU but 12 CPU, I had never encountered any performance issue and didn’t install anything new before this problem starts occurring.